Can modal logic serve as a model for Total Nothingness?
Modal logic seems like a promising language for exploring the coherence and implications of Total Nothingness (the absence of everything -- the "nothing" in "Why is there something instead of nothing?").
Are there links to other (aka, much better/smarter) attempts to put some interpretative/logical framework around nothingness so that it can be coherently discussed?

Modal Model of Total Nothingness
Let the set of worlds W be the empty set:  W:=∅
In this case, we have two interesting consequences for all propositions P:

⊨ ◻P (all propositions are necessarily true)
◇P ⊨ (no proposition can possibly be true)

This means that when we ask "Why is there something rather than nothing?" we are contemplating a possible state of affairs where the above would hold.
What I find interesting is that despite being formally consistent, these two sentences suggest that "Total Nothingness" is indeed very peculiar and metaphysically suspect. From a semantic/metaphysical perspective we are saying:

Total Nothingness (TN) implies that all propositions must be true but no proposition can be true.

This is basically saying that all propositions are both true and false, which seems an awful lot like an insonsistent/incoherent state of affairs.
Obviously, there is no formal contradiction due to the existence of vacuous truths, but it does seem to suggest that "Total Nothingness" is a suspect possibility to consider at all. It may be that we should consider "Something exists" as a necessary truth in order to avoid the myriad of paradoxes and issues wrought by trying to formalize nothingness in a rigorous way.

Wow - upvote and downvote in 2 min lol. Can someone explain why the above post may be worthy of a downvote? I actually went through the effort to explain how far I got on the issue before asking this forum, which is usually something we encourage.

First order free/inclusive logic seems suffice for your total nothingness fictionalism  thesis which is not inconsistent and is a current school of philosophy of math especially for all the infinities against the seeming Platonic existence of the said 'something' infinite...

@DoubleKnot — sounds interesting- can you add an answer that elaborates on this — you lost me at the end with all the infinities

Why are you treating Total Nothingness as a property that a collection-of-possible-worlds may possess, rather than as a property that a world may possess? The counterintuitive results you've derived suggest that this may not be the correct definition of nothingness.

@SophieSwett im using the empty set of worlds as modeling the idea of no possibility — nothingness really isn’t a property of any world or collection IMO

@Annika In that case, "nothingness" seems to be a misnomer here; perhaps "Total Impossibility" would be a more appropriate term. After all, saying that "Total Impossibility implies that [...] no proposition can be true" doesn't sound like much of a surprise.

@SophieSwett perhaps — it was just a philosophical musing of mine as I was studying modal logic and also answering a question on nothingness on this site. I think QML or free logics may be better candidates for the  idea of an absence of everything (metaphysical void)

@SophieSwett also, can you elaborate a bit more on this nothingness being a "property that a world may possess"? Does this just mean an empty domain? the accepted answer also suggested empty domains, or perhaps an empty accessibility relation. I was hoping to use the idea of an empty set of worlds as an extreme model of nothing -- where no possiblities exist. The reason being that some philosophers have argued that nothingness is so fragile it cannot withstand even possibilities (i.e., nothiness cannot be contingent).

@Annika I don't really have any more detail I'm able to go into. An empty domain seems like a reasonable way to make the idea precise.

The set of possible worlds (PWs) is not empty. It is the responsibility of the accessibility relation to determine which PWs a world can see.
The axiom ⊢ □P holds for a modal logic that Hughes and Cresswell call Ver. It has □P as an axiom, and its frame condition is that for a given world, no worlds are accessible to it at all, not even itself. In this version of modal logic, all propositions are necessary and none are possible. Ver is a normal modal logic, so it includes the necessitation rule. Ver is not inconsistent. The lack of reflexivity in the frame condition means □P → P is not a theorem. The fact that all P's are necessary does not entail that all P's are true. Even falsum is necessary, i.e. ⊢ □⊥ holds, but ⊢ ⊥ does not.
However, if I understand the question correctly, you are concerned not with worlds where no proposition is possible, but with worlds where no thing exists. So, instead of Ver, this brings quantified modal logic (QML) into view.
There are different ways of handling domains in QML. You may allow each PW to have its own domain of existing objects. However it is a theorem of first order logic with identity that something exists, i.e. ⊢ (∃x)(x=a). So to have a PW with an empty domain would result in a contradiction at that world. You could use a non-normal modal logic and allow that an empty world is impossible but is still accessible to other PWs.
The main alternative is to allow a single domain of possible objects across all PWs, and use an existence predicate, similar to those found in free logics, to indicate that a possible object exists in a particular world. With this approach, an empty world would include all possible objects but no existing ones.
Hughes and Cresswell, A New Introduction to Modal Logic, Routledge, (1996), pp. 66-67.

Thank you ! Very interesting:)
